# Node.js update and package update

Tags: node.js, npm

If I update node or a package, will it affect the applications I have that are currently dependent on the previous node/package version I had? If yes, how do I fix this? Maybe like a virtual environment :)

Comment: What do you mean by "fix this"? Do you want to avoid impacting currently deployed applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at the update from 2 standpoints. 
1. Node itself
2. Updating NPM Packages

For instance, there is the Node LTS which at this time is 6.1.10 and then there is v7.7.3. If you desire total stability then use the LTS. As Cihan said above, upgrading Node can be a long process if you have a system running on an older version.

However, if you want to test out the new `async/await` (async functions) which is already in 7.7.3 and should be released officially in 7.8 then 7.7.3 is the way to go. But keep in mind some things just may not work as you think they should or you may get some wonky results.

Also be aware depending on your server or system the Node update works differently and make sure you read the documentation for that specific system you need to upgrade.

NPM is a different ballgame. You are reliant upon many different programmers or groups of programmers. The package is depending upon their capabilities and desire to maintain the backwards compatibility. Most package creators are really good about this. Some are not.

Take a for instance. [MongoDB issued a really new driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) which is an incredible upgrade from its previous one. The new driver contains ES6 and in conjunction with the [co package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co), it is basically operating with promises.

Updating this package for MongoDB was essential for me. But it does maintain my previous code as well, (even though lots of it may be superfluous now!)

So when you think about updating Node..it is not the same as updating NPM modules. But if you wish, you can go to our project root where `package.json` exists and just type npm update and all packages will be updated. [You can update to only a specific version - take a look here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update).

Remember also, NPM itself also requires updating from time to time.

So in summary:

1. Node Version - decide which one based upon needs, requirements and your own servers.
2. NPM as NPM also needs updating from time to time
3. NPM packages can be updated constantly with `npm update` or just update to a specific version number based upon the url above.

Not as confusing as it first seems, once one gets it all down straight :)

***Good luck***

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a package that is being used by another package which a version change could break it. There are several options, if this is a personal project then you would have to either reinstall the correct version of the package or see if there are updates available otherwise for the packages that broke.

Answer (score 0):

It should not, because npm was made to resolve this issue: each project has its own dependencies, and it is totally independent with other projects.

In a word, no matter what you change, you do `npm install` in your project, npm will fix the dependency issue by itself (by checking your project's package.json)

Answer (score 0):

npm-packages sometimes change or deprecate certain functions & functionalities in newer versions. If something stops working when you update a package, you must figure out from the documentation of the updated package on how to make it work again. Many packages might also give runtime information/errors in the console about functionalities that have deprecated or that have been marked for deprecation in future versions.

npm will download specific versions of a packages' dependencies (and thus you can often have multiple version of a certain package in one project), so you shouldn't need to worry about the dependencies of the packages you are updating, only about the changes of the package itself.

Certain npm-package versions only support certain versions of Node, so updating the node version might require updating some packages. If you switch the node version, it will also switch the npm version, which will then install the correct version of the package per node version.

Some Node.js functionalities might stop working if you update Node.js. In these cases you must refer to the Node.js docs for help. Sometimes updating Node.js from a old version to a new version in a project is a large and tedious task.